# how to specify in django form that we want certain value to be inserted in database via dropdown list

Tags: python, django, database, dropdown

I am trying to save the name of the students in the database. Right now, it is saving the ID of the student instead of the name. I am using django form and i am not sure hw to tell the django form that i want to insert the student name in the database. Below is my forms.py code:

```
class studentAttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = MarkAtt 
    fields = ['studName']


def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    class_group = kwargs.pop('class_group')
    super(studentAttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['studName'].label = "Select your name:" 
    self.fields['studName'].queryset = Namelist.objects.filter(classGrp=class_group)
```

Template:

```
 <h6 style=" display: inline;"> Lab Group: {{group.classGrp}} </h6>
<h6 style="padding-left:70px; display: inline;">Day: {{group.day}} </h6>
<h6 style="padding-left: 70px;display: inline;">Time: {{group.time}} </h6>
<h6 style="padding-left: 70px;display: inline;"> Today's date: {{date.today}}</h6>

<br>
<br>

{{ form.as_p }} 

<button type ="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" >Mark Attendance</button>
```

model.py

```
class MarkAtt(models.Model):
studName = models.ForeignKey(Namelist,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True, default=None,to_field='VMSAcc')
classGrp = models.ForeignKey(GroupInfo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
currentDate = models.DateField(default=now())
week = models.IntegerField(default=0)
attendance = models.IntegerField(default=1) #1 is present


class Namelist(models.Model): 
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
program = models.CharField(max_length=10)
year = models.IntegerField(default=1)
studType = models.CharField(max_length=15)
courseType = models.CharField(max_length=15)
nationality = models.CharField(max_length=20)
VMSAcc = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
classGrp = models.ForeignKey('GroupInfo', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

right now is saving as:

id     att  studName  classId   week      date

42     1        1       1      0       2019-09-15

i want to save as

42  1   testName    1   0   2019-09-15

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: Alright done. @IainShelvington

Answer (score 0):

By default a Django `ForeignKey` field will use the primary key of the related model as the value to store in the database column, by default this is the `id` field/column. You can change the field that is used by passing [`to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) to the `ForeignKey`

```
class MarkAtt(models.Model):
    studName = models.ForeignKey(
        Namelist,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        to_field='name' # Not sure what this should be as I don't know your NameList model
    )
```

The field used must be unique

Comment: Do i need to makemigrations and migrate? because when i do, it says that django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "namelist_markatt" referencing "namelist_namelist". i have added my nameliest model above

Comment: I did not manage to migrate successfully. When i run and click submite: error "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed"